# Inno Setup - Wait for Postgres database to start

Tags: postgresql, inno-setup

In the example below I want to delay the execution of the `createuser` command until the Postgres server is up and running.

```pascal
if Exec('pg_ctl', 'start -D C:\ProgramData\PostgresQL\data', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilIdle, ResultCode) then
begin
   Sleep(10000);
   // Create our database  user
   if Exec('createuser', '-w -d -R -S testdb', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

Unfortunately using an arbitrary `Sleep()` is the only way I've managed to achieve this. The `exWaitUntilIdle` flag unsurprisingly doesn't do the trick and delay the execution long enough (if at all).

So does anyone have a more robust way of ensuring the `createuser` is not executed until the Postgres (`pg_ctl start`) server command is running, idle and ready to accept commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ewWaitUntilTerminated` flag with [`-w` switch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html):

> Wait for the startup or shutdown to complete. Waiting is the default option for shutdowns, but not startups. ... `pg_ctl` returns an exit code based on the success of the startup or shutdown.